# Dart static type errors (instead of just warnings) in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, dart

I am using the [Dart plugin for Eclipse](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/eclipse-plugin/) (not the standalone Dart Editor).

How do I configure the project/build so that static type warnings appear as errors in the Eclipse "Problems" tab? For example, this line of code actually compiles, which seems ludicrous:

```dart
int newtodo = new LIElement();
```

Running dartanalyzer at the command line gives an error, as desired:

```
dartanalyzer foo.dart
```

But instead of having to run `dartanalyzer` at the command line (or discovering them at runtime), I would like to have these errors reported on-the-fly in Eclipse.

Comment: Is the plugin provided by Google or is it third party? (Linking to the plugin would be useful)

Comment: @StevenRoose It's the Google plugin from here: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/eclipse-plugin/ I'm using the stable channel: http://www.dartlang.org/eclipse/update/channels/stable/

Answer (score 0):

If this doesn't produce a warning this is a bug according to this discussion [new user question. type warnings as errors in Eclipse](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!search/eclipse%2420plugin%2420error%7Csort%3adate/misc/iWAd8-Q2OD8/KuqShQ5bht4J)

(Also initiated from @Justin M. Keyes)